# Superimpose heatmap on a base image OpenCV Python

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, heatmap

Please look at this [github page](https://github.com/metalbubble/CAM). I want to generate heat maps in this way using Python PIL,open cv or matplotlib library. Can somebody help me figure it out? [image: Superimposed heatmaps]

I could create a heat map for my network at the same size as the input, but I am not able superimpose them. The heatmap shape is (800,800) and the base image shape is (800,800,3)

Comment: did you get any solution ? i do have same kind of requirements

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Updated Answer -- 29th April, 2022.

After the repeated comments I have decided to update this post with a better visualization.

Consider the following image:

```
img = cv2.imread('image_path')
```

[image]

I obtained a binary image after performing binary threshold on the a-channel of the LAB converted image:

```
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a_component = lab[:,:,1]
th = cv2.threshold(a_component,140,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

[image]

Applying Gaussian blur:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th,(13,13), 11)
```

[image]

The resulting heatmap:

```
heatmap_img = cv2.applyColorMap(blur, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

[image]

Finally, superimposing the heatmap over the original image:

```
super_imposed_img = cv2.addWeighted(heatmap_img, 0.5, img, 0.5, 0)
```

[image]

***Note:*** You can vary the weight parameters in the function `cv2.addWeighted` and observe the differences.

Comment: I mean the second image. please correct it! heated_img and fin look same.

Comment: Your overall method is correct. But second and third image look the same, that's it! Change the picture of second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153551/discussion-between-curio1729-and-jeru-luke).

Comment: Answer works well.  However it's odd to create a direct heatmap of an image and overlay this on the image.  I think that's what confused @curio1729.  Typically the heatmap overlaid is a result of estimation/prediction/other done on the image.

Comment: I agree. This would've been more clear if you dramatically blurred the input. I understand your heatmap is just an example, but because it is exactly the same underlying data is the original image, it doesn't look like what folks are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

My code starts from a heatmap matrix (224,224) called cam, which is applied to the original image called frame, via opencv;

and it seems to work pretty well:

```
import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2
from skimage import exposure 
...

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(...)
while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    if ret:
        #resize original frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224)) 

        #get color map
        cam = getMap(frame)
        map_img = exposure.rescale_intensity(cam, out_range=(0, 255))
        map_img = np.uint8(map_img)
        heatmap_img = cv2.applyColorMap(map_img, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

        #merge map and frame
        fin = cv2.addWeighted(heatmap_img, 0.5, frame, 0.5, 0)

        #show result
        cv2.imshow('frame', fin)
```

the getMap() function gets the headmap given the frame;

I found some interesting free videos about this topic:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTY58-51XZA&t=14s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v9usdvGU50&t=208s

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with grayscale images at this line

`super_imposed_img = cv2.addWeighted(heatmap_img, 0.5, img, 0.5, 0)`

but this one worked for me

```
plt.imshow(binary_classification_result * 0.99 + original_gray_image * 0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the page you shared, it is done through a pre-trained model. You can use backbones like ResNet:

Load the backbone:

```
resnet_50 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                                           include_top=False,
                                           weights='imagenet')
```

Preprocess the image so that it matches resnet's default

```
img = cv2.imread("/content/your_image.jpg")[:,:,::-1]
img = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
ax = plt.imshow(img)

def preprocess(img):
  # use the pre processing function of ResNet50 
  img = preprocess_input(img)
  
  #expand the dimension
  return np.expand_dims(img, 0)

input_image = preprocess(img)
```

Applying [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.03928) paper's suggestions:

```
def postprocess_activations(activations):

  output = np.abs(activations)
  output = np.sum(output, axis = -1).squeeze()

  #resize and convert to image 
  output = cv2.resize(output, (224, 224))
  output /= output.max()
  output *= 255
  return 255 - output.astype('uint8')
```

Generate and plot heatmaps:

```
def apply_heatmap(weights, img):

   #generate heat maps 
   heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(weights, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
   heatmap = cv2.addWeighted(heatmap, 0.7, img, 0.3, 0)
return heatmap
```

Plot:

```
 def plot_heatmaps(rng):
  level_maps = None
  
  #given a range of indices generate the heat maps 
  for i in rng:
    activations = get_activations_at(input_image, i)
    weights = postprocess_activations(activations)
    heatmap = apply_heatmap(weights, img)
    if level_maps is None:
      level_maps = heatmap
    else:
      level_maps = np.concatenate([level_maps, heatmap], axis = 1)
  plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
  plt.axis('off')
  ax = plt.imshow(level_maps)
plot_heatmaps(range(164, 169))
```