# Make a heatmap whit 2d points and 2 images

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, histogram2d

Good day to all,
I am trying to create a heatmap, given a set of x, y coordinate pairs extracted from a CSV file. I am using numpy.histogram2d to plot it, the heatmap gives me correct, but I need to overlay it on another image. I share my code

[Here](https://dropfiles.org/KS8P4wXM) is the CSV

```
csv = pd.read_csv("../test2.csv")
#Gets the centroid of the coords
csv["x"] = (combined_csv["x_min"]+(combined_csv["x_max"]-combined_csv["x_min"])/2).astype(int) 
csv["y"] = (combined_csv["y_min"]+(combined_csv["y_max"]-combined_csv["y_min"])/2).astype(int)
am = csv[(csv["tracking_id"] != 7) &(csv["tracking_id"] != 28)] #Some filters

#Taken from another question
def myplot(x, y, s, bins=1000):
    heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, range=[[0, 960], [0, 480]])
    heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=s)
    extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
    return heatmap.T, extent
img, extent = myplot(am["x"], am["y_max"], 16,200)
plt.imshow(img, extent=extent, origin='upper', cmap=cm.jet)
```

The previous code gives me this image

[image: Heatmap with correct extents]

I put the range between 0 and 480 for x and 0 and 960 for y, because the target image has that size, but doing this, histogram2d returns me the histogram matrix h, which is 200x200, then I use matplotlib to plot it and This graphs me correctly in the range 0-480 for x and 0-960 for y, what I need is to save said image, preserving as much information as possible in the 480x960 pixel size, and then add it with the target image using this tutorial [how to superimpose heatmap on a base image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020894/how-to-superimpose-heatmap-on-a-base-image)

```
final_img = cv2.addWeighted (heatmap_img, 0.5, image, 0.5, 0)
```

For creating something like this
[image: Example of what i wanted]
But the image and the histogram doesnt match in the sizes that i wanted.
This is the target image
[image: Target image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i fix the error by the next code, printing the two images at the same plot

```
base_image = image
sigma = 8
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (20, 16))
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(am["x"], am["y"], bins=200, range=[[0,960],[0,480]])
heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, sigma=sigma)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[-1], yedges[0]]
img = heatmap.T
ax.imshow(img, extent=extent, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.imshow(base_image, alpha = 0.5)
ax.set_xlim(0, 960)
ax.set_ylim(480,0)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.savefig("heatmap_final.png", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```